# Set screenOrientation of third-party activity according to locale

Tags: android, zendesk

I'm using ZopimChat SDK in my Android Application. Their chat library consists of a `ZopimChatActivity` which I launch from my own app.

Due to a localization issue in the library, the chat bubbles do not appear when the locale is Arabic and the device is orientated vertically; they only appear when the device is orientated horizontally. Zopim does not have a fix for this so I want to launch the activity in landscape **only** when the device is Arabic.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is just a workaround until RTL gets fully supported by the Zopim Chat SDK.

Enforce a LTR layout by specifying android:layoutDirection in Zopim's SDK layout file. This will fix the broken layout but still allow arabic languages.

Do this by creating a `zopim_chat_activity.xml` under layouts and copy the following content into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/root_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/zopim_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/chat_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

More details on [Android Layout Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection.html) and [Zopim's Developer Guide](https://developer.zendesk.com/embeddables/docs/android-chat-sdk/customization#you-cant-find-what-you-wish-to-customize)

[image: Arabic with LTR]